# Can you print $ in Scala string interpolation?

Tags: string, scala, string-interpolation

In Scala, I want to print the price of some item with string interpolation. Is it possible to display the $ character with interpolation?
This works:

```
scala> println(s"It only costs ${3 + 4} dollars")
It only costs 7 dollars
```

So why does this not work? It should still say $7, according to the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

```
scala> println(s"It only costs $${3 + 4}")
It only costs ${3 + 4}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a third `$` to the actual interpolation too. The following should work:

```
 s"It only costs $$${3 + 4} dollars"
```

The first two `$`s are for the `$` sign in the output, the third is for the interpolation. It might be easier to see this way:

```
 s"It only costs $$ ${3 + 4} dollars"
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. Just add more $